# Payment success e-mail is equal email of order confirmation

Tags: email, email-templates

I have a virtual store in magento 2.3 and it works well, except for one detail.

When I place an order I receive an email with the details of my order.

When I pay for the order, I end up receiving the same email that I had received for order confirmation.

I've already accessed the administrative panel to look for something in the settings but I haven't found anything very relevant.

I am using `ecomteck` and `proxypay` as a payment service. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the sales email configuration in admin:

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails
```

For more details check here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/sales/sales-emails.html

for the email templates you can check and update your email template from admin:

```
MARKETING > Communications > Email Templates
```

for more details to update and customize check here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

Hope this help!

Comment: I have just one template for wellcome. Another templates come from system or default template.